# Is there a difference between "anatomic" and "anatomical"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, suffixes, collocation, ic-ical

I want to say "anatomical context". Google tells me that *anatomical* in that context is preferred. An online dictionary claimed that American English does not have *anatomic* but only knows *anatomical*.

Comment: As you mention, I think the only difference would be regional, professional, or some other preference. I've never taken an anatomy class, but the few biology professors I had routinely alternated between the two without hesitation. Both are adjectives meaning the same thing.

Comment: Perhaps anatomic is used where anatomical would cause difficulty, e.g. anatomic alterations sounds better than anatomical alterations, due to the removal of repeated `al`

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in meaning or usage aside from regional preferences. The first [online dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anatomic?s=t) I checked simply redirected "anatomic" to "anatomical".

If you are curious about specific usage comparisons you can use Google's NGram viewer:

- [anatomic versus anatomical](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anatomic%2Canatomical&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canatomic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canatomical%3B%2Cc0)
- [anatomic context versus anatomical context](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anatomic+context%2Canatomical+context&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canatomic%20context%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canatomical%20context%3B%2Cc0)
- [common words following anatomic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anatomic+%2a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Canatomic%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Banatomic%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banatomic%20changes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banatomic%20structures%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banatomic%20structure%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banatomic%20location%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banatomic%20position%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banatomic%20features%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banatomic%20basis%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banatomic%20or%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banatomic%20relations%3B%2Cc0)
- [common words following anatomical](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anatomical+%2a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Canatomical%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Banatomical%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banatomical%20structure%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banatomical%20changes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banatomical%20characters%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banatomical%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banatomical%20relations%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banatomical%20studies%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banatomical%20preparations%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banatomical%20features%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Banatomical%20details%3B%2Cc0)

Short summary, "anatomical" is much more common.

Comment: Thanks for the ngrams. They allow the interpretation that "anatomic" is the more modern term for "anatomical".

Answer (score -1):

The adjectives in -ic or -ical are a sector without any system.
You find all sorts of types:

1 Both forms are possible without any difference.

2 Both forms are possible with a difference - historical, historic.

3 Only one form is possible - logical, not: logic.